# GRASS within QGIS "Python error: An error has occurred"?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, buffer

I'm very new to using GRASS within QGIS. I want to buffer a vector layer. I want to use the GRASS GUI as I can use the -c option to not create caps however I cannot launch v.buffer.distance.

[image]

I'm guessing I need to re-install something? I've just done a clean install of QGIS 2.16.0

Comment: Try using the first mentioned `v.buffer.distance` from **GRASS commands** instead of from _GRASS GIS 7 commands_?

Comment: I am getting the message "Missing dependency.This algorithm cannot be run :-(" when I try this one

https://i.gyazo.com/fa8cb794fc642f1d952f81c159083996.png

I have clicked the link on configuration but I am still a little confused